# In docker, how are storage driver and backing file system different?

Tags: docker

The `docker info` command lists both storage driver e.g. device-mapper and backing filesystem e.g. XFS. What is the meaning of these two attributes and how are they different from each other?

Answer (score 3):

The "storage driver" is software component that docker uses to manages storage.  This may be one of the `overlay` drivers, which use the `overlay` filesystem driver in the kernel, or the `devicemapper` driver, which allocates chunks of storage using the Linux device mapper, or any of several other drivers.

At some level, all of these drivers need to store *files*, which means they need to use a fileysstem.  In the case of overlay-type drivers (like `overlay`, `overlay2`, aufs) this is an existing filesystem in your host.  For the `devicemapper` driver (and similar drivers that operate on block storage), this is a filesystem created on the block devices that Docker carves out of the devicemapper storage.  The "backing filesystem" is the filesystem being used to store the files, and will be something like "XFS" or "ext4", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the Docker [storage drivers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/) use regular files on top of an existing file system. `aufs`, `overlay`, `overlay2` and `devicemapper` in `loop-lvm` mode all work via a formatted "backing filesystem".

`btrfs`, `zfs` and `devicemapper` in `direct-lvm` mode use a volume/device directly so there is no formatted file system in between the Docker container and the actual device being used. A file system is still required for Docker to store data on devices so it will create one using the reported "backing filesystem".